# Displaying numerical values as symbols on 3D map in ArcMap or ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, 3d-analyst

I have a point shp theme with fields Lat, Long, Altitude (m), and Number.

The Number field – is a numerical parameter of each point (Lat, Long)
The Altitude field – is the elevation of each point (Lat, Long) above the surface.

Is it possible to put the Number field on a 3d map (with z= Altitude)?

(I want to put a numerical value to each point (maybe by size of its symbol) and then - elevate each point on its alititude).

Any idea is it possible or not, or how I can try to do it would help.

I use ArcGIS10, so try to find this possibility in ArcMap and ArcScene.

Comment: You mean as a label?

Comment: No, no as label. I want to put a numerical value to each point (maybe by size of its symbol) and then - elevate each point on its alititude.

Comment: Yes, you can easily do all that. Set height to attribute value as well as make the symbol size based on the same value.

Comment: Where I can do it? In the Properties of theme - Symbology - then?

Comment: Can't find this option ((

Answer (score 3):

I am using 10.2.1 and there seems to be a bit of an issue with the order in which the base height is set and the symbol assigned a size based on attributes.  Long story short; it works better to set the symbol first then assign the base height both based on the same, in your case altitude, value.

**To symbolize based on an attribute field value:**
Add layer to ArcScene. Go to layer properties -> Symbology tab -> Features -> single symbol button -> in Symbol Selector select "Edit Symbol" -> In SYmbol Property Editor choose Type: 3D Simple Marker Symbol -> Style: Sphere -> OK

Back in Layer Properties -> Symbology Tab -> Choose "Advanced" -> Size -> select your field 
[image]
[image: **enter image description here**]

**To assign base height based on attribute:**

In layer properties go to the "Base Heights" tab.
In the lower part of the dialog, enable the "Use a constant value or expression" option and click the "calculator" button beside the expression text box. When expression builder is displayed, choose your altitude field and hit OK. 
Your layer will now display features at those altitudes

[image]

Example of a point layer with base height and symbol size set to a numerical attribute:
[image]